# long delay using sharedApplication when wifi is off

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, native, presentviewcontroller

So currently when this is called when on wifi, the share popup comes up almost instantly, but when its off wifi it takes 1+mins to display it.  Im looking for a fix for making it display faster when off wifi.  heres my call.

```
void _shareText(const char *text, const char *imgUrl)
{ 
    NSString * message = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:text];
    NSString * urlAddress = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:imgUrl];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];

    if (text) {
        [sharingItems addObject:message];
    }
    if (img) {
        [sharingItems addObject:img];
    }
    UIViewController *qtController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
    activityController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = qtController.view;

    [qtController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to access the app delegate like that. Ever. You need to improve the design. If you need something to present something then pass in a controller to it. Anything, just don't do what you're doing.

Comment: You are doing a bad thing here - synchronous access to the Internet on the main thread. Never do this, ever.

Comment: i appreciate the insight but that doesn't really help me figure out whats wrong.  This function is called from unity and this is simply a plugin and not a stand alone app function call.

Comment: The line `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` is downloading data from the Internet (assuming the URL isn't a local file URL). Never do this on the main UI thread. That is what is blocking your app.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you very much that was the issue removed that line and its instant now :D